# What is the meaning of の here?

Tags: meaning

```
「ぐっ、これは‥
「呪いか！？
「の、呪いなどと‥
「自らを‥　滅ぼしかねない‥　ものまでを‥使うと‥いうのか‥‥‥ヒトは‥？
```

It's a monologue from the game. That's the role of の in this sentence「の、呪いなどと‥ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is used to represent stuttering speech. 'No-noroi nado to...'.

Without the comma (pause-indicator) it would be more difficult to interpret it as a stutter.